# Tensorflow: How to load/restore a FULL model (.pb, .pbtxt, .graph, .ckpt, variables, events)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I recently switched from PyTorch to TF (1 and 2) and I am trying to acquire a good workflow with it.

**The simple things I want to do are the following:**

1. Load a full pretrained object detection model from [TF1 zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf1_detection_zoo.md) or [TF2 zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md)
2. Use `model.summary()` to inspect the network architecture of the loaded model.
3. Do inference with a pretrained loaded model.
4. Modify (e.g. reshape, drop, add) the layers and weights of the loaded model.
5. Retraining the modified loaded model.

I know that TF has the concept of graph and weights as opposed to PyTorch which just have models encompassing everything.
Nevertheless I could not find an easy and best way to load a pretraind model and the internet is full of different answers for different tf versions.

**I am really confused** because to achieve the points above I have so many different files available when I download a pretrained model from [TF1 zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf1_detection_zoo.md) (or TF2 zoo).

Take [this one](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28.tar.gz) for instance, the first in the list of the TF1 zoo.
I have the `saved_model` folder with the `saved_model.pb` and the `variables` (empty) folder, the `frozen_inference_graph.pb` the `model.ckpt` files, the `pipeline.config` and in some cases an `event` file.
Are all these different files really necessary to encode graph structure and weights?Am I missing something or this is just more complicated than necessary?
In addition, the file/folder structure is different iF you download a model from [TF2 zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md) (see image below)

[image]

**What I tried**

```
import tensorflow as tf #(v2.4)
def load_pretrained_model(self, saved_model_sub_folder,
                          mode):
    # 1. this only load an AutoTrackable object that can be use for inference but no graph
    if mode == '.pb':
        model_dir = str(TRAINED_MODEL_DIR) + saved_model_sub_folder
        model_dir = pathlib.Path(model_dir) / "saved_model"
        model = tf.saved_model.load(str(model_dir), None, '.')
        detection_model = model.signatures['serving_default']

    # 2. this returns None
    elif mode == '.graph':
        def load_graph(frozen_graph_filename):
            with tf.compat.v1.gfile.GFile(frozen_graph_filename, "rb") as f:
                graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
                graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
                return graph_def
        detection_model = tf.compat.v1.import_graph_def(load_graph(frozen_graph_filename))
    else:
        detection_model = None

    return detection_model
```

## Tl;dr

Can someone answer some of the points (1 to 5) above regarding how to load a complete (graph, weights, everything..) **customizable** tensorflow1 or tensorflow2 model in python3?